# UIScrollView paging with 2 views

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uiscrollview

I tried to implement paging with 2 views from this tutorial:

[Multiple virtual pages in a UIScrollView with just 2 child views](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html)

I wanted to modify this by putting UIScrollView to pages and in every page updating it with new content:

```
-(void)addContent:(NSString*)txt{

    int size  = 5;
    UITextView *txtView;
    int row = 0;

    //from left
    int xPlace = 0;
    //space between row's
    int rowSpace = 20;
    //from top
    int yPlace = 10;

   // int button_with = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int button_height = 20;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {


        txtView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPlace, row*rowSpace+yPlace, scrollView.frame.size.width, 2*button_height)];
        [txtView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:14]];
        txtView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        [txtView setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Numer    %@ - %i",txt,i]];

        // answerCheck.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];


        [scrollView addSubview:txtView];
        [txtView release];
        row++;
    }

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, txtView.frame.size.height*size)];
}
```

The idea is when scrolling just replace uiviewcontroller with new content. It calls:

```
- (void)setPageIndex:(NSInteger)newPageIndex
{
    pageIndex = newPageIndex;

    if (pageIndex >= 0 && pageIndex < [[DataSource sharedDataSource] numDataPages])
    {
        NSDictionary *pageData =
            [[DataSource sharedDataSource] dataForPage:pageIndex];
        label.text = @"Tekstas";//[pageData objectForKey:@"pageName"];
        textView.text = [pageData objectForKey:@"pageText"];
        [self addContent:[pageData objectForKey:@"pageText"]];
        CGRect absoluteRect = [self.view.window
            convertRect:textView.bounds
            fromView:textView];
        if (!self.view.window ||
            !CGRectIntersectsRect(
                CGRectInset(absoluteRect, TEXT_VIEW_PADDING, TEXT_VIEW_PADDING),
                [self.view.window bounds]))
        {
            textViewNeedsUpdate = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Well here I stuck. My text view is updating but new content of UIscrollView don't update in iPad simulator.

Yea I mean in iphone it works while in iPad it don't. What I could improve if I want to achieve this functionality?

Maybe there are other way to do paging from iOS 5?

I would put source that a tried to make working.

[Download source](http://minus.com/mGJ9Pgh1Z/)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a `nib` file add a `UIScrollView` with fix `width` and `height`. Now make some pages as a `UIView` and add them to `UIScrollView` with same size and same `origin`. In the main `UIView`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height * 2);
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    CGFloat h = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    [pageView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pageView1.frame.size.width, pageView1.frame.size.height)];

    [pageView2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, h, pageView2.frame.size.width, pageView2.frame.size.height)];
}
```

And don't forget to check `Paging Enabled` for `UIScrollView` in the `Attribute`s in the `nib` file.

I hope be useful for you!

Comment: Sorry I assumed your scrolling is horizontally!